# Purpose of setting GID to -1?

Tags: linux

On a CentOS 6 server, I'm seeing the following in the first line of /etc/group:

```
root:x:-1:
```

It looks like an error to me. But then again: Could there be a valid and/or clever reason for setting root's GID to -1?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Group identifier definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_identifier):

> **Special values**
>
> 0: The superuser normally has a GID of zero (0).
>
> −1: The value (gid_t) -1 is reserved by POSIX to identify an omitted
> argument.

- [More info](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chown.html).

Comment: Thanks. The POSIX documentation describes what chown() is supposed to do in case the group parameter is set specified to the special "-1": chown() is then to leave the existing group-owner on the file unchanged.
I don't see that it explains the semantics of having a user's GID=-1.